# Таблицы с перебором в drupal

Tags: php, сортировка, drupal

Как создать такую таблицу (скрин ниже) в drupal'e с возможностью сортировки и использования фильтров?
Смысл в том что изначально есть только основные колонки с значениями, а остальные должны билдиться сами с операцией каждая на каждую
[image: Таблица]

Comment: напишите более подробно, что вам нужно. как формируется основная таблица, откуда берутся данные, какая операция над ячейками, как должна ортироватся таблица, какие фильтра и т.д.

Comment: Основные колонки формируются просто беря значения с бд. Это допустим цена и у них должен быть фильтр по их значению и соответственно сортировка. Другие колонки колонки формируются сами исходя из тех которые сейчас отображены. В них например разница значений колонок созданных вручную. То есть если было 2 колонки, то должно создаться еще 2. В одной из них будет (значение поля с колонки1 - значение поля с колонки2), а во второй (значение поля с колонки2 - значения поля с колонки1). Если колонок много соответственно их надо перебрать чтобы каждая выполнила операцию с каждой + сортировка, фильтры

Comment: подключите свою таблицу к вюсам, посмотрите подключение псевдополей к ним, напишите свои хандлеры к этим полям и вы получите большие возможности, которые предоставляет вам вьюс...

Comment: Можно конкретнее как сделать самогенерируемые колонки. В каком месте надо писать для них код и как это примерно должно быть?

Answer (score 0):

Подключите свои таблицы к Views. Дальше для генерируемых полей:

1) простой вариант - используйте модуль [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

2) более правильный (по безопасности), но сложнее в реализации - посмотрите как Views PHP генерирует новые поля, по такому же принципу сделайте свои, напишите для них хандлеры.(это всё в кастомном модуле делается)